# InteliJ fails to build project after update to 2020.2

Tags: intellij-idea, build

I've recently updated IntelliJ to 2020.2 version. After that, In all of the projects I'm working with (java + maven), when I'm trying to build project (menu Build -> Build Project), I'm getting such log:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant Configuration...
Running Ant Tasks...
at index 8
Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant Configuration...
Running Ant Tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
30.07.2020 10:15 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 942 ms
```

Build via maven works.
Did anyone faced the same or similar problem? Any workarounds or magic flag to set?

I have also found stacktrace from exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 8 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 8
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.takePreloadedProcess(BuildManager.java:676)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$scheduleBuild$11(BuildManager.java:709)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:207)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 8
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:225)
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:215)
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:209)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:346)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.java:185)
    at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.AndroidBuildProcessParametersProvider.getClassPath(AndroidBuildProcessParametersProvider.java:23)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getDynamicClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getBuildProcessPluginsClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.java:40)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:1248)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$launchPreloadedBuildProcess$18(BuildManager.java:993)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    ... 12 more
2020-07-30 10:23:34,055 [1818712]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 8
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:225)
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:215)
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:209)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:346)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.java:185)
    at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.AndroidBuildProcessParametersProvider.getClassPath(AndroidBuildProcessParametersProvider.java:23)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getDynamicClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getBuildProcessPluginsClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.java:40)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:1248)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$scheduleBuild$10(BuildManager.java:809)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:207)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: try temporarily disabling the android plugin, also follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-246929

Comment: disabling the android plugin worked! Thanks Petr